# Java regex with vertical bar

Tags: java, regex

I wonder while the following regex returns false. I can't see while a "|" should not match. Any ideas? And how do I allow the pattern to match "|"?

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("([^\\*|\\\\|\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]|=|>|<])*");
boolean valid = pattern.matcher("|").matches();
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you need the | (to mean OR) in the group? Would it not just work if you have [^ab]? Do you need [^a|b] ? If that gets parsed as "not a, nor |, nor b" that would explain your situation.

Comment: Can you specify more what you want your regex to accomplish? A few more examples would be nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `[^ ]` expression matches any character not in the brackets. Since `|` is in the brackets, it is not matched. All characters (except a few, like `\` and `]`) are taken literally inside the `[^ ]` expression.

I think you meant to say something like this:

```
([^*\\{}[\]=><])*
```

This matches anything but these characters:

```
*\{}[]=><
```

To put it in a string, you would do this:

```
"([^*\\\\{}[\\]=><])*"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you misunderstand the concept of character classes in regular expressions: `[^...]` treats all characters after `^` as normal characters, not as *metacharacters*. Therefore you do not need the "OR" pipe `|` inside the class.

Since the `|` is present in the character class, and because you are using `^` to invert the set, a single pipe is not matched by your regexp.

Answer (score 0):

This print `true` :

```
 System.out.println(Pattern
            .compile("([\\||^\\*|\\||\\{|\\}|\\[|\\]|=|>|<])*")
            .matcher("|")
            .matches());
```

but the *pipe finder* `\\||` (in replacement of `\\\\|`) in other places does not work.

Kendall Frey explain you how `^` disturb your regex